# How to manage two arrays in a Model-View-Controller XCode Project

Tags: ios, arrays

I am trying to create an app with actors using a DataManger and DataModel Classes.  The first View Controller will include a list of the actors, and once you choose a specific actor, you will be transferred to a Detailed View Controller which will include the name of the actor/actress, date of birth, image and movies the actor/actress appeared on.  All these details will be derived from an Array which will be in the Data Manager Class.

I would like the information on the past participation in movies by the actor/actress to be in a local array with objects which will be part of the 'bigger array'.

See MYDataManager.m for example:

```
self.actorsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

actor = [[MYDataModel alloc] init];
actor.title = @"Hugh Jackman";
actor.biography = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Real Steel", @"Australia", @"x-men", nil];
[self.actorsArray addObject:actor];
```

I would like to take the 'actorsArray' and display it in a detailed View Controller in a textview with each movie one on top of the other, but although I have imported the DataManager and DataModel Classes, the detailed view controller does not recognize actors.biography.

Would very much appreciate your guidance and assistance.

Thanks,

Comment: You spent ages giving background (which is good, most don't), however its not very relevant and what is relevant is missing - for example where does the view controller attempt to access actor.biography and where is the declaration of biography? Where's the code for these?

Comment: Hi, the view controller tries to access actor.biography in the second View Controller which is the VC containing the details.  Tried it with the following for in loop: